# If I upgrade my system to 16.04 lts now, will it automatically upgrade to the first point release after three months?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade, stable-release-updates

If I upgrade my system to 16.04 lts now, will it automatically upgrade to the first point release after three months?
Or I must upgrade once more then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once having having freshly installed or upgraded to the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS edition, the system will automatically be upgraded to all point releases of this edition that will be released in the future. So you don't have to anything more than updating the Ubuntu 16.04 operating system as usual.